# Multiprocessing inside function

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I found what appears to be useful post here:

http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/01/16/python-parallelizing-cpu-bound-tasks-with-multiprocessing/

And I've tried this piece of code, which uses multiprocessing, but it doesn't work for me. The only change I made to the original is variable out_q=queue.Queue instead of out_q = Queue.

I believe this code was written in python 2.x and I'm using python 3.4.2

I've imported all the necessities of course.

```
def mp_factorizer(nums, nprocs):
    def worker(nums, out_q):
        """ The worker function, invoked in a process. 'nums' is a
            list of numbers to factor. The results are placed in
            a dictionary that's pushed to a queue.
        """
        outdict = {}
        for n in nums:
            outdict[n] = factorize_naive(n)
        out_q.put(outdict)

    # Each process will get 'chunksize' nums and a queue to put his out
    # dict into
    out_q = queue.Queue()
    chunksize = int(math.ceil(len(nums) / float(nprocs)))
    procs = []

    for i in range(nprocs):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(
                target=worker,
                args=(nums[chunksize * i:chunksize * (i + 1)],
                      out_q))
        procs.append(p)
        p.start()

    # Collect all results into a single result dict. We know how many dicts
    # with results to expect.
    resultdict = {}
    for i in range(nprocs):
        resultdict.update(out_q.get())

    # Wait for all worker processes to finish
    for p in procs:
        p.join()

    return resultdict
```

The error I get is

```
File "E:\....\file.py", line 109, in <module>
    print (mp_factorizer(range(100000),1))
File "E:\....\file.py", line 88, in mp_factorizer
    p.start()
File "E:\...\Python\Install\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 105, in start
    self._popen = self.+Popen(self)
File "E:\...\Python\Install\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 212, in _Popen
    return default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
File "E:\...\Python\Install\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 313, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
File "E:\...\Python\Install\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 66, in __init__
    reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)
File "E:\...\Python\Install\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 59, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class '_thread.lock'>: attribute lookup lock on _thread failed
```

Comment: I suggest you using Pool instead of an iteration for every Process. Then combined it with pool.map to execute the function. 
https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool
https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map

Comment: I'm not sure how that example code is working. Generally only functions that are defined at the top-level of a module can be executed in a worker process...

Comment: @BiRico I believe that's correct.

Comment: You don't need a `Manager.Queue`, and using one would be needlessly inefficient - do `out_q = multiprocessing.Queue()` instead.  A `queue.Queue` definitely can't work in this context.

Comment: neither `multiprocessing.Manager().Queue()` nor `multiprocessing.Queue()` have worked. I have used `Pool` before, but then I have to use `if __name__ == "__main__":` with which I have 2 problems. First I don't understand it, and second I haven't found how can it be used inside the function which can be reused

Comment: No, a `multiprocessing.Queue` works fine here - but, at least in Python 3, the worker function _must_ be at top level, not buried inside `mp_factorizer()`.

If you need more help, you really need to present the complete program you're running.  Details matter a whole lot in this area.

Comment: On ms-windows there are some [extra restrictions](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html#the-spawn-and-forkserver-start-methods) on multiprocessing, because it lacks `os.fork()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a complete program, run under Python 3.5.1 (but also works fine under Python 2).  This is so you can see *all* that needs to be done.  It doesn't actually factorize anything - the guts of the worker were replaced by very simple code, because the computations done at the lowest level are irrelevant to any of the problems you're having:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import math

def worker(nums, out_q):
    outdict = {}
    for n in nums:
        outdict[n] = 2 * n
    out_q.put(outdict)

def mp_factorizer(nums, nprocs):
    out_q = mp.Queue()
    chunksize = int(math.ceil(len(nums) / float(nprocs)))
    procs = []

    for i in range(nprocs):
        p = mp.Process(
                target=worker,
                args=(nums[chunksize * i:chunksize * (i + 1)],
                      out_q))
        procs.append(p)
        p.start()

    resultdict = {}
    for i in range(nprocs):
        resultdict.update(out_q.get())

    for p in procs:
        p.join()

    return resultdict

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(mp_factorizer(range(100), 3))
```

Comment: I've read that I should avoid comments like 'thanks' but thanks anyway :P But I have a question. Without using multiprocessing program run for about 2.7s, with multiprocessing it run for 1.7s. I've came across examples where improvments were far better. Should I expect more or is it usual?

Comment: Sorry, but there's no general answer to that - depends on all the details of the specific application you're running.  Note that for integer factorization via brute force division, the workload distribution here is naive:  for a prime `p`, that requires `O(sqrt(p))` divisions, so workers stuck with the bigger integers can be _expected_ to take longer than workers blessed with smaller integers.  The expected work per element depends on the elements.  In any case, with very small integers, the overheads of interprocess communication swamp the useful work required.

Comment: BTW, at extremes:  I've had applications that were _slower_ overall with multiprocessing.  And I've had some that ran `N` times faster with `N` cores, with no practical limit on how big `N` got.  The latter were "embarrassingly parallel":  long-running tasks with no need for interprocess synchronization or communication except, perhaps, at the start and/or end.